# What are the MX records for setting up webmail at Bluehost email?

Tags: email, dns

- My domain is registered at Dotster.
- My web is hosted at Bluehost.
- My email is using Google Workspace.

I would like to close the Google Workspace, and switch email to just webmain at Bluehost. I fail to find the proper MX records I need to set at Dotster in order to switch from Google Workspace mail to Bluehost email.

Current MX records are criptic and I don't understand it all:

```
A imap 66.96.161.153
A smtp 66.96.161.153
A mail 66.96.161.153
A webmail 66.96.161.48
MX ...
NS ...
TXT ...

and many more...
```

Which of those I need to delete?

What are the MX records required by Bluehost in order for their email service to work?

Comment: Don't Bluehost/Dotster have entire help sections on how to do this? My domain host & mail hosting company [GoDaddy/Zoho] both do; down to the finest detail, easy enough for even *me* to follow ;)

Comment: Docs are outdated, UI has changed. Currently the MX records are set under `Domain / Managa Zone` (Zone Editor).

Comment: None of those in your example are MX records at all, though?

Comment: You've shown four A records but omitted the MX records. You need to show us those and the TXT records too as they may contain information about, e.g. SPF

Answer (score 1):

My confusion came from the fact that DNS records can be set both at the domain name registrar, and also at the hosting service, and I did not know which one takes precedence.

At Bluehost, the MX records are set under `Domain / Managa Zone` (Zone Editor).